# get_post_ancestors returns empty

Tags: tags

I'm using WordPress to organize documentation for a software product I'm supporting and have hit a bit of a snag.  I have multiple FAQ documents (saved as pages) that I need to be separate pages but that I want to be able aggregate them into one FAQ master list.

To do this, I installed the "Ninja Page Categories and Tags" plugin so that I could tag each separate page with 'faq'. What I wanted to do then was query for all pages with that tag and then aggregate them into 3 lists, depending on the function of the FAQ: general, instructors, or students. Each result would be sorted based on the ancestor of the individual page.

This is the code I developed:

```
$instructors = array();
$student = array();
$general = array();

$postsByTag = get_posts('tag=faq&post_type=page&numberposts=0');

foreach($postsByTag as $post) {

    setup_postdata($post);

    $title = $post->post_title;
    $title = str_replace("FAQ: ", "", $title);

    $id = $post->ID;

    $ancestors = get_post_ancestors($post);

    if($post->ancestors && in_array( '386', $post->ancestors)) {
        $instructors[] = "<li><a href='". get_permalink()."'>$title</a></li>";
    } else if(in_array( '384', $post->ancestors)) {
        $students[] ="<li><a href='". get_permalink()."'>$title</a></li>";
    } else {
        $general[] = "<li><a href='". get_permalink()."'>$title</a></li>";
    }

}
```

The code returns all of the pages tagged with 'faq' but it sorts everything into the "general" category because it seems that get_post_ancestors returns empty, even though I know that's not the case.

What am I doing wrong here? Can anybody help me out?  Thanks!

Comment: what are you actually doing with the array `$ancestors` ? it is not used in your code. there is also no field `ancestors` in the `$post` table.

Comment: The $post->ancestors technique is something I found on the web somewhere that has worked for me in the past.  I used $ancestors to print_r the array to see what was inside (nothing) and should have removed it from this code. However, when changing $post->ancestors to $ancestors the result is the same.

Comment: what if you try `get_post_ancestors($id);` ?

Comment: same result - $ancestors is an empty array :(

Comment: try `$ancestors = get_ancestors($id,'page');`  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors

Comment: You, sir, are a genius and a lifesaver. Thank you! Wish I knew how to rep you more.

Comment: you are welcome ;-) you could add your working code as an answer and accept it - it might help others.

Comment: @Michael please move your code to an answer so this doesn't haunt site as unanswered.

Answer (score 2):

use:

`$ancestors = get_ancestors($id,'page');`

[get_ancestors()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors)

Answer (score 0):

From 2.8 to 3.4 [get_post_ancestors() could incorrectly give an empty result](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10381).

It's supposed to be [fixed in 3.5](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/21559) so it should be safe to use now.